# Speech to text with mic and hugging-face transformers., getting empty results

Tags: python, speech-recognition, audio-streaming, speech-to-text, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to implement the real time speec-to-text service using hugging face models and with my local mic. I am able see the  data coming from microphone(I printed bytes data). but I am getting empty results, when I  pass the bytes data to huggingface pipeline like below.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from transformers import pipeline

import numpy as np
model = pipeline(model="facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    #convert audio buffer to numpy array
    data = np.frombuffer(audio.get_raw_data())
    output = model(data)
    print(output)
```

output is just

```
Downloading: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2.79k/2.79k [00:00<00:00, 1.69MB/s] 
Some weights of Wav2Vec2ForCTC were not initialized from the model checkpoint at facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h and are newly initialized: ['wav2vec2.masked_spec_embed']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Say something!
C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\Anaconda3\envs\PT-BR-Sentiment\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:179: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, where=where)
C:\Users\nandurisai.venkatara\Anaconda3\envs\PT-BR-Sentiment\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:212: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  arrmean = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, keepdims=True, where=where)
{'text': ''}
```

I am expecting to recognize the voice and convert it into text